# scons linking problems depending on CC

Tags: linker, scons

I'm compiling a library that comes with a scons script. According to the documentation `scons` does everything automatically and stuff should just work.

However, the build succeeds or fails, depending on what I set `CC` to (even though I always invoke the same compiler):

```
/usr/bin/ld: context.os: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

`context.os` was built with the following arguments.

```
env cc -o context.os -c ... -Wall -O2 -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include ... context.c
```

So scons forgets the `-fPIC` argument. However if I set `CC=cc` it succeeds:

```
cc -o context.os -c ... -Wall -O2 -fPIC -DNDEBUG ...
```

The same if I set `CC="ccache cc"`:

```
ccache cc -o context.os -c ... -Wall -O2 -fPIC -DNDEBUG ...
```

And of course, with `-fPIC` set, linking succeeds in both cases.

So, I wonder how does scons position independent code trigger work and why does it screw up in the `CC="env cc"` case?

Comment: Please show us you current SConstruct where you try to setup things, or if it's too large try to minimize it to a working example that other people can run on their machines to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Additional remark: You state that SCons is supposed to do everything automatically, then please try to explain why you feel the need to explicitly set `CC` to something else...it should be picked up by `SCons` without any intervention in the default case.

Comment: @dirkbaechle It's not what I'm saying. It's what the scons doc says. It doesn't explain anything just claims that stuff just works. I don't actually want it to do things automagically, I want to be in control.